# Sqlite: replace a string modelID1/modelID2/modelID3 with name1/name2/name3/

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression, sqlite

My goal is to read the macOS Photos.app database to find out the paths of the included photos. The album and the parent folder whose name is in the *RKFolder* table can be determined for each photo. This parent folder can be located in other folders. The resulting folder path can also be read out... but in the following form:

```
modelId 1/modelID 2/modelId 3/modelID 4
```

And here I can't go any further, because I don't have enough knowledge to replace the string with the true folder names. For possible solutions it should be noted that I work with a copy of the database and therefore the folder path could also be written directly into the RKFolder table.

```
SELECT  
modelId, name,folderPath, uuid 
FROM RKFolder 
WHERE implicitAlbumUuid not NULL
```

results in (excerpt)

```
modelId name            folderPath      uuid

1                       1/              LibraryFolder
2       TopLevelAlbums  1/2/            TopLevelAlbums
7       Test            1/2/7/          kbY7RDHjRLS
8       xxx             1/2/8/          bT5WAkPWQ1
9       Test            1/2/8/9/        9PYeLZDRTne
10      ab              1/2/10/         7Cse21+1SIag
11      abc             1/2/7/11/       pNMvzDdyS%
16      efg             1/2/7/11/16/    a6R97tAxSBW
```

replace like this:

```
modelId name            folderPath                     uuid

1                       /                              LibraryFolder
2       TopLevelAlbums  /TopLevelAlbums/               TopLevelAlbums
7       Test            /TopLevelAlbums/Test/          kbY7RDHjRLS
8       xxx             /TopLevelAlbums/xxx/           bT5WAkPWQ1
9       Test            /TopLevelAlbums/xxx/Test/      9PYeLZDRTne
10      ab              /TopLevelAlbums/ab/            7Cse21+1SIag
11      abc             /TopLevelAlbums/Test/abc/      pNMvzDdyS%
16      efg             /TopLevelAlbums/Test/abc/efg/  a6R97tAxSBW
```

or even better without the TopLevelAlbums-main folder:

```
modelId name            folderPath      uuid

16      efg             /Test/abc/efg/  a6R97tAxSBW
```

Here the script that i use so far (shortened):

```
SELECT 
RKAlbumVersion.versionId, 
RKVersion.filename, 

(SELECT RKFolder.folderpath from RKFolder, RKAlbum 
WHERE RKFolder.uuid = RKAlbum.folderUuid 
and RKAlbum.modelID = RKAlbumVersion.albumId)

FROM RKMaster, RKAlbumVersion, RKVersion 
WHERE RKVersion.modelId = RKAlbumVersion.versionId 
and RKVersion.masterUuid = RKMaster.uuid
-->
Output:
77  001.JPG  1/2/7/11/16/

replace with:
77  001.JPG  /Test/abc/efg/
```

Comment: post the full expected output (not *like this* and *even better*)

Comment: i edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# number of parent directories to drop
$drop = 2;

open( $input, '<', $ARGV[0] );

# drop header lines
$line = <$input>;
$line = <$input>;

# third line is first data, being root has no name, was requested that it wasn't used, which is good, because it makes life simplier, assuming the first dir is always 1
$line = <$input>;
#@databits = split(/\s+/, $line);
$hash{'1'} = '';

while ( $line = <$input> ) {
    @databits = split(/\s+/, $line);
    $hash["$databits[0]"] = $databits[1];
}

close( $input );

open( $input, '<', $ARGV[0] );
# now we print!
# headers
$line = <$input>;
print "$line";
$line = <$input>;
print "$line";

# drop first data line
$line = <$input>;

while ( $line = <$input> ) {
    @databits = split(/\s+/, $line);
    @replace = split(/\//, $databits[2]);

    $count = 0; # start at the start
    foreach (@replace) {
        $replace[$count] = $hash[$_];
        $count++;
    }

    for (my $i=0; $i < $drop; $i++) {
       shift(@replace);
    }

    $replaced = join('/', @replace);
    if ( $replaced ne '' ) {
        print "$databits[0] $databits[1] /$replaced/ $databits[3]\n";
    }
}
```

Feed your output in as a text file, in the example below named "input". You can make nice columns with the column command.

```
$ ./replace.pl input | column -t
modelId  name  folderPath      uuid
7        Test  /Test/          kbY7RDHjRLS
8        xxx   /xxx/           bT5WAkPWQ1
9        Test  /xxx/Test/      9PYeLZDRTne
10       ab    /ab/            7Cse21+1SIag
11       abc   /Test/abc/      pNMvzDdyS%
16       efg   /Test/abc/efg/  a6R97tAxSBW
```

Comment: It works even better as desired because you removed the top level folder from the path :) ! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. And if you find it has an extra level of dir you want to remove you can adjust the $drop variable to be greater and it will drop more of them :)